# Нужно определить кол-во слов с одинаковой длиной на с#

Tags: c#

Есть строка с рандомными словами, написанными через запятую. Подскажите, как определить количество слов с одинаковой длиной.

Comment: А как вы пытаетесь сделать подсчёт и что именно не получается?

Comment: Я просто не совсем понимаю сам алгоритм определения и как это реализуется именно на с#

Comment: нужно разделить строку на слова, и сгруппировать по длине. После этого посчитать количество в каждой группе

Comment: строку на слова я разделил и закинул в массив, а вот сгруппировать по длинне не понимаю как

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb545971.aspx)

Comment: Получить массив с количеством слов каждой длины в строке без регистрации и смс `s.Split(',').GroupBy(s => s.Length).Select(n => n.Count()).ToArray();` Правда, в реальных условиях результат не очень полезен, но теперь вам есть, от чего оттолкнуться

Answer (score 4):

```
int length = 5; //длина слова
char[] splitsigns = { ',' };
List<string> words = "With,just,one,day,left,in,the,presidential,race,Hillary,Clinton,holds,a,four-point,lead,over,Donald,Trump,nationally".Split(splitsigns).ToList();

int amount = words.Count(w => w.Length == length);
```

Comment: Ок, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @Ares а минус за что поставили? Я вам помогаю, а вы мне минус, хороший вы человек!

Comment: Только в вопросе группировка по длине, а у вас подсчет количества слов одной определенной длины. Что-то не сходится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я позволю себе процитировать вопрос: "Есть строка с рандомными словами, написанными через запятую. Подскажите, как определить количество слов с одинаковой длиной". А то, что писалось в комментариях, я извините не читал, т.к. в это время писал ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Решение через LINQ уже предложили...

Поэтому предложу решение дедовским способом:

```
  Dictionary<int,int> resultDict=new Dictionary<int, int>();//Ключем словаря является длинна, а значением число повторений
        char[] splitsigns = { ',' };
        List<string> words = "With,just,one,day,left,in,the,presidential,race,Hillary,Clinton,holds,a,four-point,lead,over,Donald,Trump,nationally".Split(splitsigns).ToList();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (resultDict.ContainsKey(word.Length))
            {
                resultDict[word.Length]++;
            }
            else
            {
                resultDict.Add(word.Length,1);
            }
        }
```